# Possible Architecture Error

Tags: linux, kernel, fuse

After upgrading to Linux Kernel version 3.8.8, I noticed the FUSE module was not installed correctly. So I downloaded [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse/files/fuse-2.X/2.9.3/) fuse package(fuse-2.9.3), extracted it in the Downloads directory, configured it at the command line, then used the `make install` command and got the following error message:

```
DALEK fuse-2.9.3 # make V=1 install
Making install in include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/include'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include/fuse'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 fuse.h fuse_compat.h fuse_common.h fuse_common_compat.h fuse_lowlevel.h fuse_lowlevel_compat.h fuse_opt.h cuse_lowlevel.h '/usr/include/fuse'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 old/fuse.h ulockmgr.h '/usr/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/include'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/include'
Making install in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/lib'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse.Tpo -c -o fuse.lo fuse.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse.Tpo -c fuse.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse.o
fuse.c:219:1: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
fuse.c:219:1: warning: (near initialization for 'fuse_context_lock.__data') [-Wmissing-braces]
mv -f .deps/fuse.Tpo .deps/fuse.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_kern_chan.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_kern_chan.Tpo -c -o fuse_kern_chan.lo fuse_kern_chan.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_kern_chan.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_kern_chan.Tpo -c fuse_kern_chan.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_kern_chan.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_kern_chan.Tpo .deps/fuse_kern_chan.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_loop.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_loop.Tpo -c -o fuse_loop.lo fuse_loop.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_loop.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_loop.Tpo -c fuse_loop.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_loop.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_loop.Tpo .deps/fuse_loop.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_loop_mt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_loop_mt.Tpo -c -o fuse_loop_mt.lo fuse_loop_mt.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_loop_mt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_loop_mt.Tpo -c fuse_loop_mt.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_loop_mt.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_loop_mt.Tpo .deps/fuse_loop_mt.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_lowlevel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_lowlevel.Tpo -c -o fuse_lowlevel.lo fuse_lowlevel.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_lowlevel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_lowlevel.Tpo -c fuse_lowlevel.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_lowlevel.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_lowlevel.Tpo .deps/fuse_lowlevel.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_mt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_mt.Tpo -c -o fuse_mt.lo fuse_mt.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_mt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_mt.Tpo -c fuse_mt.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_mt.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_mt.Tpo .deps/fuse_mt.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_opt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_opt.Tpo -c -o fuse_opt.lo fuse_opt.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_opt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_opt.Tpo -c fuse_opt.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_opt.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_opt.Tpo .deps/fuse_opt.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_session.Tpo -c -o fuse_session.lo fuse_session.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_session.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_session.Tpo -c fuse_session.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_session.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_session.Tpo .deps/fuse_session.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_signals.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_signals.Tpo -c -o fuse_signals.lo fuse_signals.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT fuse_signals.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fuse_signals.Tpo -c fuse_signals.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/fuse_signals.o
mv -f .deps/fuse_signals.Tpo .deps/fuse_signals.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c -o buffer.lo buffer.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT buffer.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/buffer.Tpo -c buffer.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/buffer.o
mv -f .deps/buffer.Tpo .deps/buffer.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT cuse_lowlevel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/cuse_lowlevel.Tpo -c -o cuse_lowlevel.lo cuse_lowlevel.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT cuse_lowlevel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/cuse_lowlevel.Tpo -c cuse_lowlevel.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/cuse_lowlevel.o
mv -f .deps/cuse_lowlevel.Tpo .deps/cuse_lowlevel.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT helper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/helper.Tpo -c -o helper.lo helper.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT helper.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/helper.Tpo -c helper.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/helper.o
helper.c: In function 'fuse_daemonize':
helper.c:204:3: warning: ignoring return value of 'chdir', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
mv -f .deps/helper.Tpo .deps/helper.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT subdir.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/subdir.Tpo -c -o subdir.lo `test -f 'modules/subdir.c' || echo './'`modules/subdir.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT subdir.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/subdir.Tpo -c modules/subdir.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/subdir.o
mv -f .deps/subdir.Tpo .deps/subdir.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT iconv.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/iconv.Tpo -c -o iconv.lo `test -f 'modules/iconv.c' || echo './'`modules/iconv.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT iconv.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/iconv.Tpo -c modules/iconv.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/iconv.o
mv -f .deps/iconv.Tpo .deps/iconv.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT mount.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mount.Tpo -c -o mount.lo mount.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT mount.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mount.Tpo -c mount.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mount.o
mv -f .deps/mount.Tpo .deps/mount.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include  -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26   -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT mount_util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mount_util.Tpo -c -o mount_util.lo mount_util.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../include -I../include -DFUSERMOUNT_DIR=\"/usr/bin\" -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=26 -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -MT mount_util.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mount_util.Tpo -c mount_util.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/mount_util.o
mv -f .deps/mount_util.Tpo .deps/mount_util.Plo
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Wall -W -Wno-sign-compare -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wwrite-strings -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -pthread -ldl   -version-number 2:9:3 -Wl,--version-script,./fuse_versionscript  -o libfuse.la -rpath /usr/lib fuse.lo fuse_kern_chan.lo fuse_loop.lo fuse_loop_mt.lo fuse_lowlevel.lo fuse_mt.lo fuse_opt.lo fuse_session.lo fuse_signals.lo buffer.lo cuse_lowlevel.lo helper.lo subdir.lo iconv.lo mount.lo mount_util.lo  
libtool: link: gcc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/fuse.o .libs/fuse_kern_chan.o .libs/fuse_loop.o .libs/fuse_loop_mt.o .libs/fuse_lowlevel.o .libs/fuse_mt.o .libs/fuse_opt.o .libs/fuse_session.o .libs/fuse_signals.o .libs/buffer.o .libs/cuse_lowlevel.o .libs/helper.o .libs/subdir.o .libs/iconv.o .libs/mount.o .libs/mount_util.o   -ldl  -O2 -pthread -Wl,--version-script -Wl,./fuse_versionscript   -pthread -Wl,-soname -Wl,libfuse.so.2 -o .libs/libfuse.so.2.9.3
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/mount.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.libs/mount.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libfuse.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/fuse-2.9.3/lib'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error
```

Now I recompiled and reconfigured using the command `CFLAGS=-fPIC ./configure`, then used the `make install` command again. **This did not solve the problem**. What I wonder is if the *mount.o* object that is created by the makefile is incompatible with my architecture. That is, this package is for 32bit architecture and my machine uses the x86_64 architecture. Anyone ever encountered this error before? Particularly with this package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, this was actually not an architecture error whatsoever. Nor was it even a config error for that matter. The problem was in the Makefile which was doing a [dynamic link against statically defined archives(case 4)](https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/index.xml?part=1&chap=3).

So the way I solved it was to add the "-static" flags to the LDFLAGS in the makefile and FINALLY IT WORKED. **w00t!w00t!**

=))

I struggled with this for almost 2 weeks. Finally I can get some rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the same nature as the following (though not the FUSE part):

[ffmpeg install on CentOS 64-bit 'install with -fPIC' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506046/ffmpeg-install-on-centos-64-bit-install-with-fpic-error)

and the answer as discussed in above, is also listed below:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095&page=53&p=8080679#post8080679

and as shown in the CFLAGS below:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/harbour-devel/D4FqsmACKAU

it is not necessary "CFLAGS" itself too.

Comment: One thing I noticed upon examining the config.log file after running the configuration script is an error: >>'struct stat' has no member named 'st_atimespec'<<. I do wonder if this might be the cause of it. The link errors are in the mount.o and mount_util.o output objects. The other source code files compile just fine.

Comment: to see the details, can u please "make V=1" to whatever you are compiling?   (eg, make V=1 install).   paste the entire content to pastebin and provide the url.

Comment: Peter Teoh, the problem was linking dynamically against source code files that had data structures with the keyword **static**. Adding "-static" to the LDFLAGS fixed the problem.